# c# mvc cannot map the columns of the joined table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I use `GroupJoin` in my LINQ. But the problem is that I cannot map or extract my columns from the child table.

```
var query = db.Table.GroupJoin(db.Table3.DefaultIfEmpty(), l => l.TableID, s => s.Table3ID, (l, s) => new { ll = l, ss = s });
```

Then I have some filters here. Then iconcatenate the select below.

```
var result = query.Select(le => new ViewModel
        {
            TableID = le.ll.TableID,
            Tabble3Column= le.ss., /*this part is the error it does not show the columns of **Table3***/
        }).Distinct().ToList();
```

The error is that I cannot map the columns of **Table3**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I fixed it after 3 days of trying several syntax.

What I did was, I added the `FirstOrDefault()` on the child table (Table3)

```
var query = db.Table.GroupJoin(db.Table3.DefaultIfEmpty(), l => l.TableID, s => s.Table3ID, (l, s) => new { ll = l, ss = s.FirstOrDefault() });
```

After that I was able to map the columns of **Table3**. Hope this would help others.